# A web interface to automatically build c/c++ programs?

Tags: linux, web-applications, build-automation

Hi I have some c/c++ projects under development and version controlled with git. I would like to make/find a web interface program, which should:

- one button to build a bleeding edge target of the project.
- view build errors/logs of each build.
- export the build target (deb file for me) to a public location after a successful build.

Is there any existing/similar tool? or I should build my own one?

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) and there are many solutions available.

Answer (score 1):

Continuous integration server such as [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) is a variant